# Write failed : broken pipe

Tags: ssh, terminal

I have a headless Ubuntu server. I ran a command on the server (snapraid sync) over SSH from my Mac. The command said it would take about 6 hrs, so I left it over night.

When I came down this morning, the Terminal on the Mac said: "Write failed: broken pipe"

I'm not sure if the command executed fully. Is this a timeout issue? If so, how can I keep the SSH connection alive overnight?

Comment: [Refer Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/127369/how-to-prevent-write-failed-broken-pipe-on-ssh-connection) @Garry

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like my server is going to sleep and causing the problem.

Comment: Lets know if you are facing any issues:) @Garry

Comment: If you just need the command to execute fully, consider using nohup: `nohup snapraid sync > snapraid.out &`.  Then you can close out your terminal and the command will keep running on the server.  The output of the command is appended to *snapraid.out*.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This should resolve the problem for Mac osX version: 10.8.2

add:

```
ServerAliveInterval 120
TCPKeepAlive no
```

to this file:

```
~/.ssh/config
```

Or, if you want it to be a global change in the SSH client, to [this file](https://superuser.com/questions/364304/how-do-i-configure-ssh-on-os-x)

/private/etc/ssh_config

"ServerAliveInterval 120" basically says to "ping" the server with a NULL packet every 120s, and "TCPKeepAlive no" means to not set the SO_KEEPALIVE socket option (since you shouldn't need it with ServerAliveInterval already set, and apparently it's "spoofable" or some odd).

The servers similarly have something they could set for the same effect (ClientKeepAliveInterval) but typically you don't have control over those settings as much.

Comment: Still get the same message while unplugging laptop from thunderbolt.

Comment: @Ava that's because you disconnected your network connection. The SSH connection can only be kept alive when you don't kill it that way.

Comment: Do I need to restart my Mac? I changed ssh_config file on Yosemite and start a new SSH session but still got the error.

Answer (score 23):

You can use "screen" util for that. Just connect to the server over SSH, start screen session by "screen" command execution, start your command there and disconnect (don't exit screen session). When you think your command already done you can connect to the server and attach to your screen session where you can see the command execution result/progress (in case one should be).

See "man screen" for more details.

Comment: +1 Doesn't technically solve the question, but is probably the better solution for the user.

Comment: I think it is really better solution in several cases. For example you don't want to keep your client host running just to run a command on remote host. Another case is bad connection.

Comment: Here is a nice [step-by-step guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/keep-your-ssh-session-running-when-you-disconnect/)

Answer (score 6):

This should resolve the problem for ubuntu and linux mint
add:

```
ServerAliveInterval 120
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

to
/etc/ssh/ssh_config file

Answer (score 4):

Instead of screen I'd recommend tmux, an (arguably) better [competitor](https://superuser.com/questions/236158/tmux-vs-screen) to screen

```
tmux new-session -s {name}
```

That command creates a session.  Any time after that you want to connect:

```
tmux a -t {name}
```

Answer (score 2):

there are two solutions

1. To update server and restart server sshd

`echo "ClientAliveInterval 60" | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

2. To update client

`echo "ServerAliveInterval 60" >> ~/.ssh/config`

Answer (score 2):

After having tried to change many of above parameters in sshd_config (ClientAliveInterval, ClientMaxCount,TCPKeepAlive...) nothing had changed. I have spend hours and days to look for a solution on forums and blogs...

It appears that the problem of broken pipe which forbids to connect with ssh/sftp came from permissions settings on ChrootDirectory. 
the ChrootDirectory has to be owned by root/root with 755 permision
lower permissions 765/766/775... won't work but strongers do (eg 700)
if you need to give a write permission to connected user, you can give it in sub-directories.
if chroot is owned by sftpUser:sftpGroup, it won't work neither...

```
chroot-> root:root 755
| 
---subdirectories-> sftpUser:sftpGroup 700 up to 770
```

hope it would help

Answer (score 1):

If you're still having problem after editing /etc/ssh/sshd_config or if ~/.ssh/config
simply does not exist on your machine then I highly recommend reinstalling ssh. This solution took about a minute to fig both "Broken pipe" errors and "closed by remote host" errors.

```
sudo apt-get purge openssh-server

sudo apt update

sudo apt install openssh-server
```

Comment: I assume you mean on the Ubuntu side?

Comment: Yes, specifically the machine acting as the server in a Beowulf.  All the machines are running 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

jeremyforan's answer is correct, however I've found that if you are trying to use **scp** it is necessary to explicitly point it to a config file configured as described, it seems to not obey the normal hierarchy of config.  For example:

```
scp -F ~/.ssh/config myfile joe@myserver.com:~
```

works, while omitting the -F still results in the broken pipe error.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu : 
`ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 user@x.x.x.x`

Answer (score -2):

I use an ASUS router with two internet input lines. I appoint my IP to a certain line, and it works.